# Display Wordpress posts in multiple rows based on count

Tags: php, wordpress, posts

What I'm trying to achieve is displayed below.

What I'm trying to figure out is:

1. How to take posts and loop through to put every three in it's own div with a class of "row"
2. The more difficult problem I'm trying to solve is; If it's the first or third row, display the posts in a different layout as pictured.

If anyone has insight on how to loop through posts and put them all in rows that'd be quite helpful, and if you have insight on how to solve for the second issue, even more helpful.

I know I need to use a counter of sorts, but it seems like it's multiple counters on multiple loops.

Any insight will be appreciated. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want the modulo operator. "%"

If you check the (rowcount % 3) you can have a structure of the three rows that repeats.